# Intercept and Edit Packets over a Network Bridge

Tags: editing, bridge, packet

I've been looking around for a way to intercept a packet as it comes into my main pc, edit it, and then let it continue it's journey to the device bridges though my pc. I've tried writing a c# app to do it but only found a library for intercepting and creating packets, not editing them, and c++ apps that need to attach to a process and monitor their packets.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code of wireshark. I am quite sure it will help you a lot.
http://www.wireshark.org